# Java Date from millis - long vs int

Tags: java, time

For the following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1386633600000L)));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1386633600 * 1000)));
    }

}
```

I get the following outputs:

```
10-12-2013
24-12-1969
```

Why do they differ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the second value is using an `integer` not a `long` and has overflowed.

If you add an L at the end of either constant it will switch it to using `long` values and the difference will disappear.

This is because in the second example both values are integers. int*int = int. It only gets promoted to long if one or more of the values being multiplied (or any other mathematical operation for that matter) is a long. There is no "magic" that detects the overflow and does the promotion for you.

Even if you did `long x = int*int` it will still do the multiplication in 32 bits and then convert the result to 64 bit for the assignment.

You can also see this in more subtle places too - for example:

```
long l;
int x,y;

long result = l+x*y;
```

Even though result and l are both long, the x*y is still being done as integers since the multiplication is done first. Even if x and y individually fit in a 32 bit integer, if the product of the two does not you run into an overflow situation. The fix is to make sure its converted to long at the earliest point where you run into overflow risk - for example:

```
long result = l+((long)x)*y;
```

Comment: @Vlad: That `L` in the first argument is significant, you see. Try `System.out.println(1386633600 * 1000)` and see what you get...

Comment: @Vlad The java compiler does not do type inference, and the type checking goes the other way than you think: It first fixes the type of the expression, and then selects the appropriate method for it. In that case, it has an `int` and hence the `Date(long)` constructor is the best fit. (It doesn't matter if the method is not overloaded at all.)